# Add authentication to GAE Java endpoints

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication, endpoint

I am generating some endpoints and it works correctly, however, I would like to keep one session per client so I do not have to send the request by mail and password, but I am not sure of doing it.

This is an example of one of my endpoints

```
@Api(name = "test")
public class MyApi {

@ApiMethod(name = "printHi", httpMethod = "POST")
public Message imprimirHola(Input input) {
    Message message = new Message();
    if(datosCorrectos(input.getMail(), input.getPassword()))
        message.setMessage("Hi");
    else
        message.setMessage("authentication failed");
    return message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research in the topic you have issues with, I have found the following information that can be useful for what you are trying to achieve.

Google Cloud Platform offers the [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/) service, which has some available frameworks for user authentication. You can find detailed information and procedures about that [in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/authenticating-users#authenticating_with_google_accounts) but, in short, you can use *Firebase Auth*, *Auth0* or *Google Accounts* to authenticate a user against your endpoints ([this link](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authentication-method) will help you decide which option suits you better).

However, in order to operate with one of those options, you will need that your API is managed by Cloud Endpoints, so you will have to follow this walkthrough to [Add API Management to your API](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/adding-api-management) using OpenAPI.

Finally, [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/endpoints/getting-started) you have a working example on how to that using Java.

I know it is a lot of information, but I think you will be able to solve the authentication issue with your Java API just by reading more detailed information in [this last documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks), and move step by step in the "Getting Started" dropdown menu in the left of this page.